# Alternative to Tabs, Sub Tabs List View with Details (Android)

Tags: gui-design, mobile, android, tabs, listview

I'm trying to create an android app with tabs, one of the tabs has a list view that leads to a detail view that has 3 different sections that I have separated with tabs.

- Application
- Action Bar
- Tab 1 (Schedule)

  - List View

    - Detail View (in modal)
- Tab 2 (Trainees)

  - Detail View

    - Detail Action Bar
    - Sub Tab 1 (Info)
    - Sub Tab 2 (Weigh-ins)

      - List View

        - Detail View (drop-down accordion)
    - Sub Tab 3 (Sessions)

      - List View

        - Detail View (in modal)
- Tab 3 (Exercises)

  - List View

    - Detail View (in modal)

The Problem with this is in the detail view of tab 2. The detail action bar and sub tabs combined with the normal action bar and take up a lot of the screen.

[image]

I do not want to have to use a hamburger menu since I have found with that the phrase "Out of sight, out of mind" applies there. Is there an alternate navigation set up I can use? Does one even exist?

Answer (score 3):

**Yes**. Don't apply the global action bar to the detail page, make it contextual. [image]

Comment: Agreed... You don't need to keep that action bar when you go to the trainer page. The page for each trainee can be "modal," providing its own focused experience.

Comment: Should I also remove the main navigation tabs?

Comment: Sorry, what I meant was should the navigation tabs be contextual as well? Showing the tabs for the trainee INSTEAD of the main tabs?

Comment: When on the main screen show only the main navigation (Schedule, Trainees, Exercises). When the user drills down into a trainee show only the contextual tabs (Info, Weigh-ins, Sessions). The header with the App Title, and icons (plus, search and ellipses) should be persistent. The only exception would be that when the user drills into a trainee the system should display the Trainee Name in place of the App Title (Personal Trainer Pal) with a left arrow. The left arrow on press should take the user back to the main screen with the trainees displayed. Hope this helps.

Comment: My pleasure. If this is the answer you intended to proceed with I would appreciate if you would mark it as the accepted response.